# Java variables in Azure Pipelines

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-java-sdk

We use Azure DevOps pipelines and I found the following strings during compiling:

[image]

is it necessary for pipeline process (internal for azure) or something included, which is not necessary for us (we don't use Java apps in our solution)?

Thanks

Comment: Well which kind of agent are you using (and if not self hosted which VM)?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft Host Agent you have pre-installed software and you don't have control over it (you can install sth new if you needed, but there is no point for removing sth what i already there). Please check [included software here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).

If you use self-hosted agent this is up to you what you have as you are responsible for [agent's capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#capabilities)

> Your agent's capabilities are cataloged and advertised in the pool so that only the builds and releases it can handle are assigned to it. See Build and release agent capabilities.
>
> In many cases, after you deploy an agent, you'll need to install software or utilities. Generally you should install on your agents whatever software and tools you use on your development machine.
>
> For example, if your build includes the npm task, then the build won't run unless there's a build agent in the pool that has npm installed.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Krzysztof Madej.

According to the log, it seems that you are using windows agent, such as windows-2019 and vs2017-win2016, it contain the Java variables you shared before

Hosted agent has installed software for each hosted agent and it contain a broad range of tools and software. We can see the installed software for each hosted agent by choosing the Included Software [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) in the table.

Also We could add task **bash** and enter the script `printenv` to list all environment variable.

If you are using self-hosted agent, it will check your local machine environment variable and agent capabilities.